# Where can I find information about the development history of QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I know very little about early versions of `QGIS` (far far away from now..) and i'm feeling curious :-)

I am looking for various information about the past of QGIS, including:

- Do you know in what year the software was created?
- By whom? (Was it a single person or a group? Do you have some names? Nationality?)

Comment: I think this is too broad for focussed Q&A because it asks five questions and does not indicate any research undertaken prior to asking each.

Comment: There's no problem with multiple closely related questions in a post (it would be ridiculous to divide this into five posts).  But the third question about anecdotes is too vague and subjective for this site.

Comment: @whuber I was not suggesting that five questions be asked. Just asking who started QGIS would probably have uncovered most of the same information but I suspect a Google search could be done first to find that and focus it to something harder to find.

Comment: @PolyGeo It sounds like you agree, then, that it would be incorrect to suggest that all nominally multiple-question posts be closed on the basis of containing several questions. I am glad you are taking a nuanced approach that is willing to consider that a set of closely related questions can be suitable for our site.

Comment: @whuber I would suggest that almost all (but not all) multiple question posts should be closed as too broad. My trigger for too broad is when answers are expected that need to be cross-referenced to the parts of the question to which they relate.

Comment: "most" rather than "almost all" may be a better wording above.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I just woke up, I'll edit the question to better reflect the requirements of SE.

Comment: Edit : The question "Do you have any anecdotes about the use of these early versions? (funny or really annoying bug)" is removed (broad).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Year created: 2002
- By: Gary Sherman

[image: Number of QGIS committees by year.]

A fun fact about the early releases: The release names were names of dogs, then planets.  The release names are now based on the towns that we hold the hackfests.

There is some early history in keynote that Tim gave at FOSS4G at:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQ8ytFJE_Wk

Sources: http://spatialgalaxy.net/2011/09/23/history-of-qgis-committers/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QGIS

Comment: That's a great answer Nathan, is there any stats on the users? It would be a bit difficult as the product doesn't need to be registered and a single download can do multiple installs... it would be interesting to see the increase in QGIS users. Perhaps one way to look at it is the number of downloads/year and GIS.SE posts with the QGIS tag per year. Leasye, the bug tracker for QGIS is online at https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues but only goes back a approximately one year.

Comment: This website can also help : https://www.openhub.net/p/qgis He gives stats about lines of code, commits per month, contributors per month since 2002